# VMWare workstation & dirty hard drives of VM Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, vmware-workstation

I have a VMWare virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04. 
Host OS - Windows 8.1

On Ubuntu installed program that heavily utilizes hard drives, very often rewrites some files.

Size of the all Ubuntu files - about 30Gb  and doesn't change over time. 
But size of the VM files in the host OS - 65 Gb, and it keeps growing very fast.

Common VMWare tools can not reduce size of VM files at all. How I can do it manually?

Comment: Are you using thick or thin provisioning?

Comment: mmmm I don't know )) I just created virtual machine using VMWare workstation. It uses space on my hard drive to store guest OS data (not dedicated hard drive)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your hypothesis that the growing disks are due to heavy write access, you could

- mount the virtual disks into another linux system into /mnt/old
- provide an empty virtual disk at /mnt/new
- `cd /mnt/old ; tar cf - . | tar xf - -C /mnt/new` maybe with suitable options for sparse files
- compare old and new virtual disk sizes

I'm not sure how you determined the 30G disk usage. If this number is based on "du -sh" it might not be what the OS really has still in use. Use "df -h" for that. A substantial difference is usually caused by processes holding on to open files that have been deleted/replaced. For that case `lsof | grep DEL` usually helps.